Maildir viewer, but for Windows
I want to analyze a backup archive of Maildir files, i.e. sift through a large number of business e-mails, including complete header information and any documents in the attachment. Some of the e-mails and attached files may have forensic value, so the archive must be accessed strictly read-only in order to preserve originality.
Here is a screenshot of the folder structure. The files inside the cur folders have names such as
5286806512.M446716P63625.mail,S=1879880,W=2290677_2,Sa
5286806512.M256849P63625.mail,S=4059,W=6731_2,FS
5286806512.M860467P63625.mail,S=19629,W=43009_2,S

Is there a free Maildir viewer for Windows with which I can browse through the e-mails, run keyword searches, filter and sort e.g. by date or recipient, extract attachments, display e-mails chronologically vs. as conversations etc.?
